# HTML/XML limit for maximum "src" attribute size

Tags: html, xml, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum length of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)

What is the maximum limit on say img "src" path in HTML/XML? Is this mentioned in any specification that I can look at? For e.g. following img tag is what I'm specifically concerned about:

img class="frame-1" **src="image/Blue%20hills12345678012345678.jpg"** alt="Blue%20hills123456780123456789012345678901234567891111aa.jpg"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the HTML spec, the `src` attribute contains a URI (usually a URL). There's, AFAIK, no standard max bound on the size of a URI, but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/166749) for some practical limits.

Comment: Thanks larsmans, that answers my question. I assume its the same for xml as well.

Answer (score 1):

The specifications doesn't limit the size of an URL, but browsers do.

Older versions of Internet Explorer has the shortest limitation, at about 2048 characters.